# Fetching data from database using Pusher to make a large application real-time stops the browser

Tags: php, jquery, real-time, pusher

When I use Pusher on a testcase it works perfectly well; all contents appear on different browsers in real-time.

However, when I put the same code on a large LAMP Stack application it slows the browsers and eventually stops them.   Browsers first display a slow-spinning gray circle on the tab, then display browser not responding.  The larger the data the slower the browser becomes, so if I post a comment, it takes some time, then it goes through.  If I post an image plus comment, it takes more time to go through, then the browser stops.   And, if I post a video plus comment, it doesn’t go through. 
 Eventually, it freezes my PC.

Here is my code on the testcase:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<form id="comment_form" class='input-group form-row' action="comment_add1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5" cols="70"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group-prepend">
   <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn btn-info" value="Submit" form="comment_form" />
  </div>
</form>

<div id="display_comment"></div>
<div id="comment_message"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/5.1/pusher.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Add comment
 $(document).on('click change', '.submit', function() {

if ($(this).is('.submit')) {

  $.ajax({
   url:"comment_add1.php",
   method:"POST",
   data: new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '') {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
    }
   }
  });

 location.reload();

      $(this).closest('form').submit();
      e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      return false;
    }

});


 // Fetch comment
 function load_comment(){
        $.ajax({
         url:"comment_fetch1.php",
         method:"POST",
         success:function(data){
          $('#display_comment').html(data);
         }
        })
 };

 load_comment();

/*=======================================
=            Pusher Frontend            =
=======================================*/

var pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, {
  cluster: 'us3',
  forceTLS: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
 load_comment(data);
});

/*=====  End of Pusher Frontend  ======*/

// End of (document).ready(function){}
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**comment_fetch.php**

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_testcase_pusher', 'root', '');

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comment 
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
$date = '';
$comment = '';

foreach($result as $row)

{
 $output .= '
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
  <div class="panel-body"><pre>'.$row["comment"].'</pre></div>
 </div>
 ';
}

echo $output;

/*==============================
=            Pusher  Backend          =
==============================*/
require('pusher_config.php');
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$options = array(
  'cluster' => 'us3',
  'useTLS' => true
);

$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, APP_ID,
  $options
);

$data = '';

$pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);

/*=====  End of Pusher Backend  ======*/
?>
```

Comment: It's possible that you are loading your browsers memory up .. Have you tried looking at the developer's console (especially the console and network tab) ?  Your browser has a finite amount of memory -- As does your PC --

Comment: I forgot to look at the console.  I do it now.

Comment: Network tab, just says `comment_fetch.php` continuously.

Comment: And the browser is frozen even though I had already reopened it and restarted XAMPP.

Comment: I tried it on a different browser, it says status 101.  But it froze both the browser and my PC.  How about if I check the developer's console on the testcase?

Comment: On the testcase, which has exactly the same Pusher's code, on network tab, 1st it says status pending while the comment has already appeared on the other browser, then it says status 200.    Apparently you are right that I am over-loading my browser's and PC's memory.   What is the solution to this?